# AWS API Gateway: Use dynamic part of resource in integration uri

Tags: dynamic, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, api-gateway

I want to re-use a dynamic resource value for the integration uri in an AWS CDK API Gateway definition.

Let's say I have two services:

service-football
service-tennis
both have one endpoint "players".

Now I want one single api gateway definition for both, the football and the tennis players. I try to dynamically define this as follows:

```py
endpt = rest_api.root.add_resource(path_part='endpoint')
sport_endpt = endpt.add_resource("{sport}")
players_endpt = sport_endpt.add_resource("players")
    
players_endpt.add_method(
    http_method='GET',
    ...
    integration=apigw.Integration(
        type=_apigw.IntegrationType.HTTP,
        integration_http_method='GET',
        uri=uri + '/service-*HERE_THE_SPORT_PARAM*/players',
    )
)
```

In the integration part I want to create the uri part dynamically with the dynamic resource value {sport}, so that I get something like /service-football/players or /service-tennis/players which I can extend easily by just creating service endpoints with the same conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a single API endpoint definition, you need to have the sport included as a path parameter, so it would be something like `BASE_URI/service/{sport}/players`.

The corresponding cdk would be

```py
endpt = rest_api.root.add_resource(path_part='endpoint')
service_endpt = endpt.add_resource(path_part='service')
sport_endpt = service_endpt.add_resource("{sport}")
players_endpt = sport_endpt.add_resource("players")
    
players_endpt.add_method(
    http_method='GET',
    ...
    integration=apigw.Integration(
        type=_apigw.IntegrationType.HTTP,
        integration_http_method='GET',
        uri=uri + '/service/{sport}/players',
    )
)
```